# Invoke a function in a sibling component when an event happens in current component

Tags: angular, angular-components

My application has one parent component and two sibling components.

```
<feed>
 <status></status>
 <post></post>
</feed>
```

what i'm trying to achieve is when i write something in status component which is basically a text field and submit , i should pass that data into post component and invoke another function in post component to update its view. But i have no idea how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement a service and have an event emitter, you can than inject that service into both the components and emit from `status` component and listen to it in `post` component

common.service.ts :

```
@Output() public somethingChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

status.component.ts :

```
someFunc() {
    this.commonService.somethingChanged.emit({
        data: "Dummy Data For Post Component"
    })
}
```

post.component.ts :

```
constructor(
    public commonService: CommonService
) {
    this.commonService.somethingChanged.subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log("Data from status component", data);
    })
}
```

Now whenever `someFunc` in status component will be called, the listener in post component will be executed. You need to ensure that both the components share the same instance of `CommonService` i.e both `status` and `post` component are part of same `NgModule`, if they aren't than you would need to create singleton of `CommonService` using shared module with `forRoot`.

Comment: This helped me too, I didn't know a service could have @Output to it.

Comment: don't forget to unsubsribe from somethingChanged in post.component.ts in ngOnDestroy method. Otherwise a memory leak will occur.